# LocalStorage not updated with the latest value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to react and I am experimenting with incrementing a value and storing it into local storage. I was able to write down the following code bellow, however, the last instance of the incremented number is not updated the local storage value. For example, if I press "+1" twice and the number is 10, the dom is updated twice and shows the number 12, but the value stored on local storage is 11. Why is this happening?

```
import { useState } from 'react'


function About () {

    const localStorageValue = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('value'))
    const [value, setValue] = useState(localStorageValue);

    function remove() {
        setValue((add) => add - 1)
        localStorage.setItem('value', parseInt(value))
    }

    function add() {
        setValue((add) => add + 1)
        localStorage.setItem('value', parseInt(value))
    }


    return (
        <>
            <h1>About page</h1>

            <button onClick={remove}>-1</button>
            {value}
            <button onClick={add}>+1</button>
        </>
    )
}

export default About;
```

Comment: There is [a local storage hook](https://usehooks.com/useLocalStorage/) that you might find easier to use with React. Looks like it's also available [here](https://github.com/streamich/react-use).

Answer (score 0):

Use the refresh button and it will reflect the changes

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Issue here is asynchronous behaviour of `setState` i.e. it will update the state value with a bit of delay and without stopping for complete execution of `setState` it will proceed to next line of code i.e. `localStorage.setItem()`.

In your case `setState` is `setValue`

So to overcome this you can need some kind of callback function behaviour to achieve this with `useState` hook so you can use `useEffect` for the same as follows:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function About() {
    const localStorageValue = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("value"));
    const [value, setValue] = useState(localStorageValue);

    useEffect(() => {
        localStorage.setItem("value", parseInt(value));
    }, [value]); // only rerun if value changes

    function remove() {
        setValue((add) => add - 1);
    }

    function add() {
        setValue((add) => add + 1);
    }

    return (
        <>
            <h1>About page</h1>

            <button onClick={remove}>-1</button>
            {value}
            <button onClick={add}>+1</button>
        </>
    );
}

export default About;
```

This will ensure that it will run everytime after successive state update.

PS. There's no need to use `parseInt` while storing as it will be stored as string only.